# Robomongo - silent install

Tags: installation, silent, robo3t

I want to install silently [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) on Windows 7, but I can't find any command that would be helpful in this task.
It seems like good old `/s` does not work here.

Do anybody knows if it's even possible with this installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me with a capital /S